# WebUSB Access denied because of cdc_acm

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webusb

I have accessed a scale with WebUSB and received my demanded output (aka the weight). It perfectly runs on Windows but I want to deploy it on an ASUS ChromeBox. I have set up an udev- rule and unbinded the device from the cdc_acm driver. The problem is that the cdc_acm claims the interface again every time I reconnect the device.

What can/should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebUSB doesn't currently support detaching kernel drivers on Linux, but it is being considered: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1099521

You could add `cdc_acm` to the kernel module blacklist in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` to prevent it from loading. Alternatively you could consider using the [Web Serial API](https://wicg.github.io/serial/) to interact with the CDC ACM driver instead of WebUSB.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I have tried to blacklist the driver on the ChromeBox but it keeps getting loaded. On Ubuntu, it works. Do you have an advice?

Comment: On Chrome OS devices there is a list of serial devices for which the driver is automatically detached when requested by Chrome. Blocking drivers by modifying the system configuration (in developer mode) is not supported.

Using the Serial API is the solution I would recommended.

Comment: @ReillyGrant How can i get device info with the Serial API?

Comment: The `getInfo()` method has device properties (only VID/PID at the moment).

Comment: @ReillyGrant How can I call the `getInfo()` method?